# returnTradeHistory in poloniex always returns empty list

Tags: python, bitcoin, algorithmic-trading, poloniex

I'm using the python wrapper provided by poloniex: [wrapper](http://pastebin.com/fbkheaRb)

The method I'm trying to run now is:

```
def returnTradeHistory(self,currencyPair):
    return self.api_query('returnTradeHistory',{"currencyPair":currencyPair})
```

But the method **`.returnTradeHistory()`** always returns an empty list, even if I have already made a trade, using that coin. The other methods are working as expected, even those that also need the private API ( return balances for example ).

Here is a print of the output:
[image: script running]

And here is a print of my trade history:
[image: Trading history]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, reading the documentation once more I saw this:

> *Returns your trade history for a given market, specified by the* `currencyPair` *POST parameter. You may specify* `"all"` *as the* `currencyPair` *to receive your trade history for all markets. You may optionally specify a range via* `start` *and/or* `end` *POST parameters, given in UNIX timestamp format; **if you do not specify a range, it will be limited to one day**.*

So, sorry for the dumb question.